# list of files available in hdfs recursive directory and sub directory lookup using python and generating pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, hdfs

Is there any way to list all **Files** (only) from given directory (which may contain sub-directories too) under **HDFS** using python function? and finally, generate pandas data frame with a list of all those available files?

I have tried using **pywebhdfs** but it only provides **Files / Directory** from given folder - it doesn't perform recursive search/lookup.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many client libraries like hdfs3 and hdfsCLI that can be used for the purpose.
A sample on how you can achieve it through hdfsCLI

```
from hdfs import Config
import posixpath as psp

client = Config().get_client('dev')

fnames = client.list('/cdc')
print(fnames)

fpaths = [
  psp.join(dpath, fname)
  for dpath, _, fnames in client.walk('/cdc')
  for fname in fnames
]

print(fpaths)
```

The client connection can be achieved using a `.hdfscli.cfg` file in your home directory (or at some other path configured through `HDFSCLI_CONFIG` environment variable.
A sample look of config file is as below:

```
[global]
default.alias = dev

[dev.alias]
url = http://<host>:<port>
```

You may also chose to get the connection using `InsecureClient`

Pls refer to https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html for usage and download instructions.